# RecyclerView item's height changes after calling setVisibility() method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try to implement delete with swipe in RecyclerView. After item is swiped I call notifyItemChanged() and change visibility of views in onBindViewHolder method.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (isPendingRemoval(position)) {
        holder.textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);            
        holder.undoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

        holder.undoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = mPendingRunnables.get(adapterPosition);
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(pendingRemovalRunnable);
                mPendingRunnables.remove(adapterPosition);
                notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
            }
        });

    } else {
        holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        holder.undoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.textView.setText(someText);            
    }
}
```

But after that deleted item's height changes. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pDPs.png)

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item_button_undo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/button_undo_text"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

What can I do to save item's height?

Comment: Where.? I don't see any problem in screen shot

Comment: I want height to be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the Button width to match_parent and just change it's visibility and not the one of the TextView (that apparently gives the height of the item), this way the item should keep height and width and the button should be visible over the TextView hiding it

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (isPendingRemoval(position)) {
        // holder.textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);            
        holder.undoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

        holder.undoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = mPendingRunnables.get(adapterPosition);
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(pendingRemovalRunnable);
                mPendingRunnables.remove(adapterPosition);
                notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
            }
        });

    } else {
        // holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        holder.undoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.textView.setText(someText);            
    }
}
```

Comment: It works if use holder.textView.setText() after  button visibility change.